# Relation between literary parallelism and Jesus

Tags: jesus, 1-samuel, judges, parallelism

In Judges 3:7-11 (NASB)

> 7 So the sons of Israel did what was evil in the sight of the Lord, and they forgot the Lord their God and served the Baals and the Asheroth. 8 Then the anger of the Lord was kindled against Israel, so that He sold them into the hand of Cushan-rishathaim, king of Mesopotamia; and the sons of Israel served Cushan-rishathaim for eight years.
>
> 9 But the sons of Israel cried out to the Lord, and the Lord raised up a deliverer for the sons of Israel to set them free, Othniel the son of Kenaz, Caleb’s younger brother. 10 And the Spirit of the Lord came upon him, and he judged Israel. When he went to war, the Lord handed over to him Cushan-rishathaim king of Mesopotamia, so that he prevailed over Cushan-rishathaim. 11 Then the land was at rest for forty years. And Othniel the son of Kenaz died.

In 1 Samuel 12:8-11 (NASB)

> 8 When Jacob went into Egypt and your fathers cried out to the Lord, then the Lord sent Moses and Aaron who brought your fathers out of Egypt and settled them in this place. 9 But they forgot the Lord their God, so He sold them into the hand of Sisera, commander of the army of Hazor, and into the hand of the Philistines, and into the hand of the king of Moab, and they fought against them. 10 They cried out to the Lord and said, ‘We have sinned, because we have abandoned the Lord and have served the Baals and the Ashtaroth; but now save us from the hands of our enemies, and we will serve You.’ 11 Then the Lord sent Jerubbaal, Bedan, Jephthah, and Samuel, and saved you from the hands of your enemies all around, so that you lived in security.

What's the relation between the literary parallelism found in Judges / 1 Samuel and Jesus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OT is filled with "types" of Jesus and the OP has observed two more.  One of the most famous is that of Joseph as a type of Jesus:

- both are rejected by their own people
- both became servants
- both are betrayed for silver
- both are falsely accused and face false witnesses
- both attain stations at the "right hand" of the respective thrones (Joseph at Pharaoh's throne and Christ at the throne of God)
- Joseph was 30 years old when he stood before Pharaoh, and Jesus was about the same age according to the bible when he began his ministry
- Both became a Savior to their people by going to Egypt; Joseph as a lad of 17 and Jesus as a baby (Matt 2:15)

Such types in the OT illustrate what Jesus said to the two men on the road to Emmaus, in Luke 24:25-27 -

> Then Jesus said to them, “O foolish ones, how slow are your hearts to
> believe all that the prophets have spoken! Was it not necessary for
> the Christ to suffer these things and then to enter His glory?” And
> beginning with Moses and all the Prophets, He explained to them what
> was written in all the Scriptures about Himself.

Again in John 5:39 we read:

> You study the Scriptures diligently because you think that in them you
> have eternal life. These are the very Scriptures that testify about
> me

Thus, Jesus wanted the disciples and all Christians) to see Jesus portrayed throughout the Bible in all its stories.  The Judges of ancient Israel were also supposed to represent Jesus.  This can also be seen in the earthly monarch of David and the royal promises.

While David and his successors were earthly kings, they were to recognize that the real king of Israel was God.  1 Sam 8:7, 8, 24:6, 2 Sam 19:21, 1 Chron 28:5, 2 Chron 9:8, 13:8, Ps 5:2, 44:4.  See also 1 Sam 12:14.  Further, the eternal nature of David's monarchy was to be fulfilled in Jesus as declared by the angel in Luke 1:32, 33 -

> He will be great and will be called the Son of the Most High. The Lord
> God will give Him the throne of His father David, and He will reign
> over the house of Jacob forever. His kingdom will never end!”